# Is it possible to make Vpn app using flutter and dart

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, vpn

I tried using this package to make VPN connection app but it dose not support the connection type like (L2TP or PPTP)

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vpn

Answer (score 0):

i found that code on source, seems like pptp connection

```
  /// Use given credentials to connect VPN (ikev2-eap).
  /// This will create a background VPN service.
  static Future<Null> simpleConnect(
      String address, String username, String password) async {
    await _channel.invokeMethod('connect',
        {'address': address, 'username': username, 'password': password});
  }
```

Comment: it is seems like the connection type is ikev2-eap ?? how can i change the type connection type ??